# Problem: List of Abbreviation includes abbreviations from list of figures instead of main content

Tags: table-of-contents, acronyms

I am still learning latex. I want the list of abbreviations to include those abbreviations which first occur in the main content (start of the report) instead of abbreviations from the miscellaneous pages such as 'list of figures' or from 'list of listings'. The command used for acronyms is
`\usepackage[acronym,indexonlyfirst,nomain]`

I have tried
`\usepackage[acronym, indexonlymain,nofirst]`
`\usepackage[acronym]`
which does not work as per my needs.
The below picture shows my problem. I would like to avoid the roman numbered pages on the list of abbreviation page and instead it must pick the abbreviations from the main content.
[image]

This is a problem because once the abbreviation is mentioned in its expanded form in the list of figures page, it is mentioned in its short form in the main content which is absurd. Rather its first occurrence must be in the main content with the expanded form. I hope you understand my issue.
Any help is great.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Could you have some insights bitte?

Comment: Please prepare a complete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allow others to reproduce the output you get.

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided any code so we can not tell what you have done. If the answer below does not help then edit your question to include a MINIMAL Working Example (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`).

I'm guessing that you have figure captions like `\caption{title and abbreviation}` which gets put in the fugure and also added to the LoF.

Use the optional argument to the caption

```
\caption[title for the LoF without abbreviation]{title and abbreviation for the figure}
```